# What is the meaning of this C++ operator?

Tags: c++

I have no idea about C++, and I need to change some code to other programming languages. Can someone tell me what the following line of code means?

```
double a = v(i) / 2. / sigma0 / sqrt(_R(i) / P(i));
```

Specifically, `. /` is not clear to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's operator `/`, `.` is a part of the previous instruction, that means `2.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Please notice that:

```
double a = v(i) / 2. / sigma0 / sqrt(_R(i) / P(i));
```

is different from:

```
double a = v(i) / 2 / sigma0 / sqrt(_R(i) / P(i));
```

As answered by other answers， `/` is clearly the division operator. And `2.` means 2.0, adding a '.', as pointed out by comments under the original answer, makes it a floating point literal.

For more on how c++ handles similar situations, you may check these links:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/44-implicit-type-conversion-coercion/

Comment: There's no "implicit cast" of an `int` here. The decimal point makes it a [floating point literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal).